# What patterns can help me organize big project with modular structure?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, architecture, system

For example, I have a project with ~500 pages and a domain with big variety of different functions. Also there are requirements about modular structure of the app. It should be not so hard to turn off and turh on some of the features. There is caviet that features can integrate with each other.

#### Example

- You can create different documents in the app (bills).
- Also you can create payments which pay those bills.
- Also you can you can bind payment with bill while creating a payment and vice versa.

There are cases when you do not have access to documents functionality, only payments. So, you cannot bind payments with documents and do not see documents in UI.

If I have ~30 such modules with different interconnections, how can I organize the app so I can turn on and off any of modules?

Comment: Is your system web application, mobile application or SPA for example? This information could narrow possible solutions. Do you need some kind remote way to turn off/on modules on the fly or runtime?

Comment: Web Api + SPA. I do not need to do it on the fly for one user. But different users can see different state of the system at the same time.

Comment: Could you try to explain the use case better? For me, it is not so clear yet how your modules work. For example, is BILL and PAYMENT example of modules? Or what do you mean modules here?

Comment: Also, when you talk about a module, do you mean always some kind of UI that should be visible or hidden? Or is the module some function that is happening on the background and not has any user interface parts? For example, when you TURN OFF module, should it hide some part UI block in SPA application or just change behavior in the server side.

Comment: By module I mean a set of functionality. For example, DOCUMENTS module is several pages, main menu item, some background logic. Another module is PAYMENTS. I could have some UI injections of one module in the other (link for binding a document to a payment in payment creation ui).